# How to start session in external web through php

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to login to an external page through php and curl but I am new to this.

This is my code:

```
    <?php 

    $username = ".........@gmail.com";
    $password = "........";


$url = "https://lobby.ikariam.gameforge.com/login.php";
$cookie= "c:\\cookies.txt";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) die(curl_error($ch));
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($response);
$tokens = $dom->getElementsByTagName("meta");
for ($i = 0; $i < $tokens->length; $i++)
{
    $meta = $tokens->item($i);
    if($meta->getAttribute('name') == 'csrf-token')
    $token = $meta->getAttribute('content');
}
$postinfo = "email=".$username."&password=".$password."&_csrf=".$token;
echo $token; //debug info
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postinfo);
$html = curl_exec($ch);
    print($html);
if (curl_errno($ch)) print curl_error($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
?>
```

But when i try it, i give this error:

Notice: Undefined variable: token in C:\xampp\htdocs\Ikariam\index.php on line 25

Notice: Undefined variable: token in C:\xampp\htdocs\Ikariam\index.php on line 26
405 Not Allowed
nginx/1.16.1
1

Answer (score 1):

Define `$token` before the loop and search until you find the desired token:

```
$token = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < $tokens->length; $i++)
{
    $meta = $tokens->item($i);
    if ($meta->getAttribute('name') == 'csrf-token') {
        $token = $meta->getAttribute('content');
        break; // exit the loop if the token is found
    }
}
```

Of course, you need to make sure you have a `csrf-token` in the `$tokens` array.

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Thanks, but now i have this "error" 405 Not Allowed
nginx/1.16.1 I think it is related to the url